# Sip server get online users list

Tags: sip, kamailio

Good day!

Can anyone point me to right direction? The question is  - I
want to get list of registered users (to find out who is online at the
moment) from sip server. I'm using kamailio on server side and exosip
library on client side.

The best way is to get some method in exosip lib, but I didn't find any..
My guess is do something like this :
 Put req text into Sip ping messages, modify server side to parse req and send online users list in answer. But it seems not a good idea...

I tried   to find something in  RFC 3261 and failured... Can someone
help and tell what to do or where to look for the answer?

Comment: If you need to know who is online use: `kamctl ul show`. I don't understand what you wrote in 2 & 3 paragraph... Why you need to get users info from kamailio using SIP protocol?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sorry for my badly written post- what I wanted to find out - is how to get online user list on client side. Because when I want to call someone via VoIP I want to be sure if he is online. PS I have custom VoIP client do I can add anything on client side.

Comment: Check Kamailio presence module

Answer (score 0):

*late answer, but may worth anyway!*

There is no SIP feature designed to retreive people's status. (This would be an open hole for spammer!)

The only available standard (presence) will allow you to retrieve the status of your freinds, but you need to know their identity first.

If you really wish to have such features, you should do without SIP:

- configure your kamailio to use a database (such as myslq)
- implement some web page able to access the "location" table from kamailio database
- retreive this web page from your SIP application. (with HTTPS, not SIP)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Event Package for Registrations ([RFC3680](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3680)). But both Sip server (kamailio) and SIP client (exosip library) need to support this.